# How do you flag or tag DOM elements dynamically in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a simple filter component setup so when you click a button, a computed value updates the UI with the filtered data list.

I cant figure out the "Vue way" to somehow tag or flag a button that has been clicked, so in the code i can say "filter is already on, turn it off"

In jquery i would do something like this which allow me to to run different code if the filter is on

```
$('button').on('click', func(){ $this.addClass('hasFilter')} )
```

Vue snippet

```
<button class="button is-info" v-on:click="filterCats('Logos')">Logos</button>
<button class="button is-info" v-on:click="filterCats('Print')">Print</button>

computed: {
  filteredData: function () {
    return this.filteredCats
  }
},
methods: {
  filterCats: function (cat) {
    let items = this.filteredCats
    let filterCount = 0
    let result = {}
    Object.keys(items).forEach(key => {
      const item = items[key]
      if (item.cat_names.some(cat_names => cat_names === cat)) {
        result[key] = item
        filterCount++
      }
    })

    event.target.classList.add('active')
    this.filteredCats = result
  }
},
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html and you can keep a status in `data`

Comment: In Vue, instead of keeping track of state in the DOM, you keep track of it in `data`.

Comment: this doesnt work when you have multiple buttons, updated my code. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `filtered` `data` property to control that.

Declare it:

```
  data() {
    return {
      // ...
      filtered: false                                              // added this line
    }
  },
```

And then change it when clicked:

```
<button class="button is-info" v-on:click="filterCats('Logos'); filtered = true">Logos</button>
```

Another possibility is to keep the template as it is (`v-on:click="filterCats('Logos');"`) and change the flag on the method instead:

```
   methods: {
    filterCats: function (cat) {
      // ...
      this.filteredCats = result
      this.filtered = true;                                        // added this line
    }
  },
```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      filteredCats: {
       one: {cat_names: ['Logos'], title: {rendered: 'one'}},
        two: {cat_names: ['Two'], title: {rendered: 'two'}},
        three: {cat_names: ['Three'], title: {rendered: 'three'}}
      },
      filtered: false                                              // added this line
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredData: function () {
      return this.filteredCats
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterCats: function (cat) {
      let items = this.filteredCats
      let filterCount = 0
      let result = {}
      Object.keys(items).forEach(key => {
        const item = items[key]
        if (item.cat_names.some(cat_names => cat_names === cat)) {
          result[key] = item
          filterCount++
        }
      })

      event.target.classList.add('active')
      this.filteredCats = result
      this.filtered = true;                                        // added this line
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  filtered? {{ filtered }}
  <br>
  <button class="button is-info" v-on:click="filterCats('Logos');">Logos</button>

  <div class="list-item" v-for="asset in filteredData">
      <a>{{ asset.title.rendered }}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo (changing the template):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      filteredCats: {
       one: {cat_names: ['Logos'], title: {rendered: 'one'}},
        two: {cat_names: ['Two'], title: {rendered: 'two'}},
        three: {cat_names: ['Three'], title: {rendered: 'three'}}
      },
      filtered: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredData: function () {
      return this.filteredCats
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterCats: function (cat) {
      let items = this.filteredCats
      let filterCount = 0
      let result = {}
      Object.keys(items).forEach(key => {
        const item = items[key]
        if (item.cat_names.some(cat_names => cat_names === cat)) {
          result[key] = item
          filterCount++
        }
      })

      event.target.classList.add('active')
      this.filteredCats = result
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  filtered? {{ filtered }}
  <br>
  <button class="button is-info" v-on:click="filterCats('Logos'); filtered = true">Logos</button>

  <div class="list-item" v-for="asset in filteredData">
      <a>{{ asset.title.rendered }}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes great sense thanks! but how would this work with multiple buttons? When you filter one, the filtered data updates for everything.

Comment: You'd have to create one property for each button. You could also create an array and reference using an index, if you prefer.